# How can I avoid these case statements?

Tags: haskell, refactoring, monads

How can I express the following without the nested case statements? Specifically, I would like to do the steps in order, and call fail if any of the steps hit the "bad" branch.

```
loadData :: IO [Market]
loadData = do
  filedata <- B.readFile "markets.json"
  case parseData filedata of
    Left err -> fail err
    Right v -> do
      case fromJSON v of
        Error err -> fail err
        Success a -> return a
```

Comment: This should help: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the exception monad transformer here.  Something like this (utterly untested):

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Except

type MyMonadStack a = ExceptT String IO a

loadData :: MyMonadStack [Market]
loadData = do filedata <- lift $ B.readFile "markets.json"
              v <- ExceptT $ parseData filedata
              a <- ExceptT $ toEither $ fromJSON v
              return a

toEither :: WhateverTypeFromJSONReturns a b -> Either a b
toEither (Error a) = Left a
toEither (Success b) = Right b
```

Comment: There is this line `case a of {Left e -> return (Left e) ; Right x -> runExceptT (k x)}` in the definition of bind for `ExceptT`. So it returns something instead of failing with error, so the author of the question needs to define his own monad transformer.

Comment: @user3237465: Oh, I deliberately did not do it that way, but forgot to point that out. Basically, if you factor things in terms of the monad transformer, the `fail` bits from the original question should arguably be factored out of the `loadData` action.

Answer (score 4):

If `parseData` and `fromJSON` both have `Either Err a` as their codomain, where `Err` is a fixed type (maybe defined by you), then you can use the `Either e` monad instance like so:

```
loadData :: IO (Either Err [Market])
loadData = do
  filedata <- B.readFile "markets.json"
  return $ parseData filedata >>= fromJSON
```

Or, if you want to be extra slick, you can use a particular [monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-3.0.2) to do the same thing.

Comment: An explanation for a broader audience of "codomain" in this context might help the questioner understand this answer.

Comment: I would love to hear more. I didn't select it because fromJSON returns `Result a` instead of either. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html

Comment: By codomain I mean the rightmost type after all -> signs. What's the idiomatic term for this? Range?

Comment: Yes, `fromJSON` has the wrong type, but `Result a` looks like just `Either String a` (two constructors, `Error String` and `Success a`, just like `Left String` and `Right a`), so all we need is a function `String -> Err`, which we can run on the output of `fromJSON`, to get a function with the right type.